# How to force a page refresh in Chrome on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome

I'm testing a mobile website and when changing javascript it doesn't seem to refresh it, even when using the "reload" in the menu or when appending a random variable, for example "?test=123" to the end of the url.
I also force quite the app but still no luck.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Is this problem Chrome/iOS specific or does it happen with other browsers/OSes as well? If it is not restricted to this single combination you might get better answers on a site focused on web development in general (we can help you with migrating the question to a better suited SE site if you prefer).

Comment: Definitely edit more info into the question. If you just want to know if the chrome app has some reload functionality, we're the place to host this. If you instead need to know specific code to program into your website to force a reload, we can find the best place for the question once those details/distinction are clear.

Comment: thanks. I want to know if the chrome app has some reload functionality that will force a complete reload including javascript. Or a way to delete the browser cache completely in the chrome app

Answer (score 4):

Per your comment that "a way to delete the browser cache completely" may be suitable, you can go to the **Chrome menu** → **Settings** → **Privacy** and clear the cache.

Answer (score 4):

IMO it sounds like client side caching is *not* your problem. It's more likely you're running into a server side cache problem. If you're using a CDN (cloudflare, cloudfront, etc.) to serve assets, make absolutely sure that you're expiring assets appropriately.

Barring that, I recommend using Chrome [in Incognito mode](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-browse-incognito-on-chrome-for-ios/) which does not persist a long lived client cache.

Comment: Opening the page on an Incognito tab worked for me. A stylesheet was cached and I was able to get the fresh version then.

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware that this is an old question, but perhaps this will help others.

In the browser you're using, tap the address bar, and type:

`javascript:location.reload(true);`

or

`data:text/html,<script>location.reload(true);</script>`

This has been tested on iPhone XS, in Google Chrome.

Comment: The first works great—IF you make it a bookmark! I named it “Hard Refesh” and pasted in just the `javascript…` line and then going to the page and selecting the bookmark will actually do a full refresh and reload all CSS, images, etc even if cached. Yes!

Answer (score -2):

Yep. Maybe first you should clean up Chrome browser cache and some temporary files, and see how it goes.

Comment: Your answer should elaborate on *how* to clean up those temporary files